# Android speech recognizer works fine on 5.0.1 but doesn't work on 5.1

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am working on create a speech recognition service on android and followed previous works from others here. The old version was based on android 5.0.1 and it worked perfectly fine.
However, when I try to move it to android 5.1, it always stops in the onError function in the recognition listener with a error code 7, which means ERROR_NO_MATCH.
I don't know why this happened. is there any difference on using speech recognizer in Android 5.0.1 and 5.1? 
If someone can help me, I will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
public class speechrecognitionService extends Service
{
protected static AudioManager mAudioManager; 
protected SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
protected final Messenger mServerMessenger = new Messenger(new     IncomingHandler(this));

protected boolean mIsListening;
protected volatile boolean mIsCountDownOn;
private static boolean mIsStreamSolo;
private static String voiceCommand;

static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING = 1;
static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL = 2;
public static final String TAG = null;
public static final String FEEDBACK = "com.kut.kutcamera";
public static final String COMMAND = "command";
public static final String standardVoiceCommand = "take a photo";
public static final String voiceCommandAlt1 = "take photo";
public static final String voiceCommandAlt2 = "photo";
public static final String voiceCommandAlt3 = "take";

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                     RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                                     this.getPackageName());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Say your command loud and clear please.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
    //startListenting(true);
    //int result = super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


}

protected static class IncomingHandler extends Handler
{
    private WeakReference<speechrecognitionService> mtarget;

    IncomingHandler(speechrecognitionService target)
    {
        mtarget = new WeakReference<speechrecognitionService>(target);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        final speechrecognitionService target = mtarget.get();

        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING:

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                {
                    // turn off beep sound  
                    if (!mIsStreamSolo)
                    {
                        mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
                        mIsStreamSolo = true;
                    }
                }
                 if (!target.mIsListening)
                 {
                     target.mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(target.mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                     target.mIsListening = true;
                    //Log.d(TAG, "message start listening"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                 }
                 break;

             case MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL:
                if (mIsStreamSolo)
               {
                    mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
                    mIsStreamSolo = false;
               }
                  target.mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                  target.mIsListening = false;
                  //Log.d(TAG, "message canceled recognizer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                  break;
         }
   } 
} 

// Count down timer for Jelly Bean work around
protected CountDownTimer mNoSpeechCountDown = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
{

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        mIsCountDownOn = false;
        Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL);
        try
        {
            mServerMessenger.send(message);
            message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
            mServerMessenger.send(message);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {

        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mIsCountDownOn)
    {
        mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
    }
    if (mSpeechRecognizer != null)
    {
        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
        //Toast.makeText(speechrecognitionService.this, "the recognizer is destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
{

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
    {
        // speech input will be processed, so there is no need for count down anymore
        if (mIsCountDownOn)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }               
        //Log.d(TAG, "onBeginingOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech()
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + error);

        if ((error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH)
                || (error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT)){
            if (mIsCountDownOn)
            {
                mIsCountDownOn = false;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
            }
            mIsListening = false;
            Log.d("TESTING: SPEECH SERVICE: CALL START", "onError()");
            startListening(true);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = true;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.start();

        }
        //Toast.makeText(speechrecognitionService.this, "Please say your command loudly and clearly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results)
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        ArrayList strlist = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        voiceCommand = (String) strlist.get(0);
        Toast.makeText(speechrecognitionService.this, voiceCommand, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (voiceCommand.equals(standardVoiceCommand) || voiceCommand.equals(voiceCommandAlt1)
                || voiceCommand.equals(voiceCommandAlt2)||voiceCommand.equals(voiceCommandAlt3))
            publishResults();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(speechrecognitionService.this, "Say the command again please.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
    {

    }

    private void startListening(boolean bMuteSound){
        Log.d("TESTING: SPEECH SERVICE: startListening()", mIsListening? "true":"false");
        if (bMuteSound==true && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)//Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            // turn off beep sound
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
        }
        if (!mIsListening)
        {
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
            //recognizeSpeechDirectly ();
            mIsListening = true;

        }
    }

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private void publishResults() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(FEEDBACK);
    intent.putExtra(COMMAND, voiceCommand);
    //intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
  }
```

}